# Is there a way to see how much time it took for a task to finish running in Task Scheduler (Windows)?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have a task that starts a .bat file with some operation with files on a file system and I am interested in evaluating the time it takes for a task to get the job done.

I can see date/time when the task started and status in the History tab of the Task Properties, but am unable to figure out the time it took for the task to actually perform the work. I am able to record this by writing own log file with Python or .bat, but was looking for a way to get this information directly from Task Scheduler (Windows 2008R2/2012).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you're looking for information on how long the task ran or if you're looking for information on how long it took each operation of the task to run. If the former then see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: I missed that one could see the task information and status in Server Manager, too. That was exactly that I was in need for.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > TaskScheduler > Operational. You should be able to find Task Completed in there.

Comment: I am not able to see how much time it took to run the task as I can do in Server Manager.